# WhatsApp integration on iOS 10 does not work: "You'll need to continue in the app"

Tags: iphone, siri, whatsapp.app, ios

I am using an iPhone 5S and I just updated to iOS 10. 
I enabled the Siri support towards WhatsApp in Settings > Siri > App Support.

However, when I use Siri and ask, for example "Send a message to XXX using WhatsApp saying Hello", Siri tells me *"Sorry, you'll need to continue in the app"*.

It seems like the integration has not been enabled yet. Does someone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling WhatsApp helped in my case.

Comment: What about all my backups, old chats and media? Are they still there, after restoring the app?

Comment: @mgiordi Use the backup functionality within the app to back up your chats and media. Providing you are logged in to iCloud, these will be available to restore once reinstalled.

Answer (score 1):

According [this news article](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/news/whatsapp-update-brings-ios-10-compatibility-letting-people-send-messages-just-using-siri-a7308686.html), the update to WhatsApp is being pushed out now.  Give it a few hours and make sure the app is updated then try again.

> The company has pushed out its update for iOS 10, meaning that it’s now compatible with the variety of useful features that the new iPhones update includes. And many of those are most important for things like WhatsApp.
>
> The new iOS update brings huge improvements to Siri, which is now much smarter. Those changes are central to apps like WhatsApp, because the two can now be integrated.
>
> So, finally, asking Siri to “Send a message on WhatsApp to John saying hello”, will actually make that happen. A special window will pop up with a preview of the message, just like has long happened with the built-in messaging app, and you can then send it off to people.

Comment: I still have the same issue, and no other Whatsapp updates were released. Do you know if the problem will be fixed?

Comment: No, I don't work for WhatsApp.  It looks like you need to contact WhatsApp customer support.